Deserialising ZonedDateTime from Oracle generate different milliseconds on Azure pipeline
I am using Oracle database with Spring JPA. And I am facing weird situation while trying to run my unit test cases over the Azure pipeline.
I have installed JAVA 17.0.8 on my local machine while Azure pipelines are running on JAVA 17.0.10 (Vendor: Eclipse Adoptium). This can be possibly a bug with this JAVA version 17.0.10 provided by Eclipse Adoptium.
Note that, When I try to run unit test cases on my local using the Oracle database docker container, all the test cases are running successfully. But, when I try to run test cases over Azure pipeline, I am getting following errors.
2024-05-02T09:54:41.8995194Z [ERROR]   MyCustomer.testUpdateCustomerEndDate:145 Multiple Failures (1 failure)
2024-05-02T09:54:41.8996036Z    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <2024-05-02T09:54:39.709796802Z[Etc/UTC]> but was: <2024-05-02T09:54:39.709797Z[Etc/UTC]>|

Here, we can see that, there is very minor difference in the milliseconds (709796802Z vs  709797Z) which got deserialised from Oracle database.
I am using following Maven@4 task in Azure pipeline for running the test cases.
- task: Maven@4
  displayName: 'Run Unit Test'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'test'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Test Over Oracle Container'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '17'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: true
    options: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER) -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dunit-test=true'

Below is the glimpse of code in my test case class where I am setting the endDate and calling JPA method to update the MyCustomer entity object.
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        int updateCount = MyCustomerDao.updateCustomerEndDate(customer.getId(), , now);

        assertEquals(1, updateCount);

        MyCustomer customerSaved = MyCustomerDao.findCustomerById(customer.getId());

        assertAll(
                () -> assertNotNull(customerSaved),
                () -> assertEquals(now, customerSaved.getEndDate())
        );

When I try to run the same test case on my local laptop using "mvn test" command, it works fine. What can be the problem ? Any suggestions/feedback appreciated.

Edit : The test cases are running successfully If I change the Java version from 17 to 1.11 in Azure Maven@4 task as below.
Hence, this problem seems to be more specific with Azure pipeline as I am already running test successfully on my local machine where I have installed Java "17.0.8"
- task: Maven@4
  displayName: 'Run Unit Test'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'test'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Test Over Oracle Container'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: true
    options: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER) -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dunit-test=true'


Glad to know it works with 1.11 version.  The version 17 could be a typo,  it should be 1.17 in your 1st yaml. The detail version is 17.0.11(windows-latest agent) and 17.0.10(ubuntu-latest agent), which is slightly different with your local version 17.0.8. As the only difference is the jdk version, suppose like an issue from jdk side. If possible, you can check same version jdk on local, will it work fine?

Just notice you edit the info with jdk version 17.0.10. As it's resolved with 1.11 version, it's recommended to answer yourself so that it can help others who have same query, thanks.

It is working with version 1.11 but that is not the fix. We need to migrate our APIs to JDK 17. So, I am still trying to find a workaround to solve the problem. I will try installing JDK 17.0.10 on my local and confirm if it works or not.

As a workaround, we could install jdk 17.0.8 on agent machine via task JavaToolInstaller@0, or install the jdk on a self-hosted agent, then specify the jdk version with path for maven@4 task. I will add the details below, thanks.

As it only works with jdk 17.0.8, you can install it by JavaToolInstaller@0 on the agent, or prepare a self-hosted agent. On maven@4 task, specify the jdk path to find the specific version.

Download jdk 17.0.8 installation, and put it in the repo.



Task JavaToolInstaller@0 will help to install the jdk and setup JAVA_HOME.

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'builds/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.8+7-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: 'builds/binaries/externals'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: false

- script: |
    java -version        # check the new jdk version.
    printenv | sort



In maven@4 task, specify the jdk path instead of jdkversion.


- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'Path'          # path here
    jdkDirectory: '$(JAVA_HOME)'    # java_home
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false

It will use 17.0.8 jdk for the maven task:


I fix this problem temporarily.
This problem seems to be more specific to Java version 17.0.10 (Vendor: Eclipse Adoptium) running on ubuntu agent of Azure DevOps.
I downgraded the JAVA version to 1.11 and test cases are running successfully.
In future, I need to migrate all pipelines to JAVA17, so I am waiting for new version on JAVA17 on ubuntu agent to be provided by platform team.
